# CSS: how to hide radiobutton inside button appereance?

Tags: html, css

I've some radiobuttons: Good, Better and Best.

I want to  change its appearance to a rectangle button.

Like this:

[image]

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/dyvvjgx

Code:

```
<div class="fps-budget" data-fps-budget="good">
            <input id="fps_good" type="radio" name="budget" value="good" class="visually-hidden">
            <label for="fps_good">
              <img data-fps-budget-img="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/Good_29ea1531-4b74-4ead-be87-8f053f8efc96_320x140.jpg?v=1601266077" alt="Good.">
              <span class="h3">Good.</span>
      </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: `id` must be unique for each tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS you can put this.
input[type=“radio”] {
display: “none”
}
Then you can change the style of the label.